# Imageresizer API Endpoint for uploading images

Tags: imageresizer

Are there possibilities for uploading images to imageresizer via the application itself?

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer provides APIs to make creating such an endpoint much easier, (Build() accepts file upload objects as well a streams), but ImageResizer does not expose one itself.

Comment: Thank you. I think we will move to aws or azure and use the api from the cloud storage for that.